# how do I show distinct column (Name) and the numbers it has come up in a month or year?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Name   Count (*)  Date

Blue    2         01-NOV-22
Blue    1         03-NOV-22
Blue    3         11-NOV-22
Green   5         01-NOV-22
Green   5         11-NOV-22
```

Expected

```
Name    count   Date
Blue    6     Nov2022
Green   10    Nov2022
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle database? You have tagged your question for both.

Comment: sorry, using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: What exactly is your question? It looks like you need a simple aggregation. [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/)

Answer (score 1):

It is a `sum` function, while other values are name and date (formatted as you wanted it).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (name, cnt, datum) as
  2    (select 'Blue', 2, date '2022-11-01' from dual union all
  3     select 'Blue', 1, date '2022-11-03' from dual union all
  4     select 'Blue', 3, date '2022-11-11' from dual union all
  5     select 'Green',5, date '2022-11-01' from dual union all
  6     select 'Green',5, date '2022-11-11' from dual
  7    )
```

Query:

```
  8  select name,
  9         sum(cnt) as cnt,
 10         to_char(datum, 'Monyyyy', 'nls_date_language = english') datum
 11  from test
 12  group by name, to_char(datum, 'Monyyyy', 'nls_date_language = english');

NAME         CNT DATUM
----- ---------- ----------------
Blue           6 Nov2022
Green         10 Nov2022

SQL>
```

Comment: Mr. Little foot, I took the liberty to use a a different date format.  Maybe you did not read my comments.  If you sort by "Monyyyy" it not sorted correctly.  For instance, Nov2022 and Nov2021 are next to each other.  If you sort on "yyyyMM" you always get a lexical sort that is correct!

Comment: It is not about **date format**, @CRAFTYDBA. Besides, there's no ORDER BY clause anywhere in your query (nor it seems to be important to the OP). I was *complaining* about query itself. Did you run it? What result did you get? I'll tell you: it returns total of 3 for Blue and 2 for Green, while result should be 6 and 10 (respectively). Shortly: your query doesn't return desired result (regardless of date format).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a table called "my_table" that has fields my_name as string and my_date as a data.  Just al

```
select 
  my_name,
  to_char(my_date, 'yyyy-mm') as fmt_date,
  sum(my_count) as total
from
  my_table
group by 
  my_name,
  to_char(my_date, 'yyyy-mm')
```

This will give you results as the following.

```
my_name    fmt_date     total
Blue       202211       6
Green      202211       10
```

Using this format for a date is better since it is sorted in the correct order.

This can be tested in SQL Fiddle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, it won't return desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding discussion about row ordering here is a bit bigger sample dataset:

```sql
WITH 
    tbl (A_NAME, A_NUMBER, A_DATE) AS
        (
            Select 'Black', 3, To_Date('01.11.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 'Black', 1, To_Date('03.11.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'Blue', 2, To_Date('01.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 'Blue', 1, To_Date('03.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 'Blue', 3, To_Date('11.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'Greeen', 5, To_Date('01.11.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'Green', 5, To_Date('01.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 'Green', 5, To_Date('11.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual 
            
        )
```

The basic answer is just aggregation with group by:

```sql
SELECT      A_NAME, Sum(A_NUMBER) "CNT", To_Char(A_DATE, 'Mon yyyy') "A_DATE"
FROM        tbl
GROUP BY    A_NAME, To_Char(A_DATE, 'Mon yyyy')
```

Resulting dataset of this code is not sorted at all and Oracle could return the result in any order. Here is the result:

```sql
-- NO ORDER BY 
A_NAME        CNT A_DATE 
------ ---------- --------
Black           4 Nov 2021 
Green          10 Nov 2022 
Blue            6 Nov 2022 
Green           5 Nov 2021
```

If you want the result in certain order (ASC [default] Or DESC) then you should define it with ORDER BY. A few possibilities are here:

```sql
-- ORDER BY    A_NAME
A_NAME        CNT A_DATE 
------ ---------- --------
Black           4 Nov 2021 
Blue            6 Nov 2022 
Green           5 Nov 2021 
Green          10 Nov 2022

-- ORDER BY    A_DATE
A_NAME        CNT A_DATE 
------ ---------- --------
Black           4 Nov 2021 
Green           5 Nov 2021 
Blue            6 Nov 2022 
Green          10 Nov 2022

-- ORDER BY    A_DATE, A_NAME
A_NAME        CNT A_DATE 
------ ---------- --------
Black           4 Nov 2021 
Green           5 Nov 2021 
Blue            6 Nov 2022 
Green          10 Nov 2022 

-- ORDER BY    A_DATE DESC, A_NAME
A_NAME        CNT A_DATE 
------ ---------- --------
Blue            6 Nov 2022 
Green          10 Nov 2022 
Black           4 Nov 2021 
Green           5 Nov 2021
```

... you can even  order it by the resulting SUM()

```sql
-- ORDER BY    Sum(A_NUMBER) DESC
A_NAME        CNT A_DATE 
------ ---------- --------
Green          10 Nov 2022 
Blue            6 Nov 2022 
Green           5 Nov 2021 
Black           4 Nov 2021
```